# Replacement /equivalent of „over(partition by..)“ for older version 5.5.60 MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

Is there any option for rewriting clause „**over(partition by**..)“  in the script below for an older version 5.5.60 of MariaDB please? This script is ok for newer version howewer the clause is unusable (not executable) for MariaDB-5.5.60

```
select
    a.year,
    a.company,
    b.dt,
    case 
        when a.year = 2018 
            then sum(b.quantity)
        when a.year = 2020
            then sum(b.quantity) 
                - sum(case when a.year = 2018 then sum(b.quantity) else 0 end) 
                  over(partition by a.company, b.dt)
    end quantity
from taba a
inner join tabb b on b.id = a.id
group by
    a.year,
    a.company,
    b.dt
```

Does anybody know some work-around of this clause?

I would be grateful for correction of mentioned script for older version of MariaDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since window functions were introduced in [MarieDB 10.2.0](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-1020-release-notes/), consider joining on aggregate subquery to equate the conditional `SUM() OVER()` call.

```
select
    a.year,
    a.company,
    b.dt,
    case 
        when a.year = 2018 
            then sum(b.quantity)
        when a.year = 2020
            then sum(b.quantity) - sub.calc_qty
    end quantity
from taba a
inner join tabb b on b.id = a.id
inner join 
   (select sub_a.company, sub_b.dt,
           sum(case
                    when sub_a.year = 2018
                    then sub_b.quantity
                    else 0     
               end) as calc_qty
    from taba sub_a
    inner join tabb sub_b on sub_b.id = sub_a.id
    group by sub_a.company, sub_b.dt
   ) sub
 on sub.company = a.company 
 and sub.dt = b.dt

group by
    a.year,
    a.company,
    b.dt
```

Comment: Looks like "2008" was a typo?  Were there other typos?